# How to configure my entity event listener to run before vendors listener | Priorities for Doctrine entity event listener

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine, symfony-2.8

Disclaimer:
Yes, this question might seems as duplicate, but as there are no definitive/universal answers about how to fix this, I suppose that this might be good to arise this one more time, and possibly we will get definitive way to cope with the described problem.

Hello, I have faced with the problem that in my vendor folder I have some default `doctrine.orm.entity_listener` which has `prePersist` method with some logic inside.
But in some circumstances, I won't let this `prePersist` event happen and stop persist/flush the current entity.
I tried to cope with this case with `priority` tag attribute, but this doesn't works, as it seems doctrine doesn't support priorities for entity listeners.
Could somebody give me an advice on how I can put my own `prePersist` listener to run before vendors one?

Here is the sample of my code with priority:

```
acme_demo.event_listener.vendor_entity:
    class: 'Acme\Bundle\AcmeDemoBundle\EventListener\VendorEntityListener'
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, entity: '%vendor_entity.class%', event: prePersist, priority: 1000 }
```

Best regards.